# Are there good iPhone SQLite3 tutorials which really start from scratch?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I always find something that starts somewhere in the middle, where the database already exists or where some special classes or files have already been added to the project. I want to see the first steps, since they're crucial. i.e. somebody said the database has to be copied into a readwriteable dir on the iphone. Anyone knows a complete tutorial on this?

(no, I don't want to use Core Data or OS 3.0)

Answer (score 1):

What about SQLite Persistent Objects? I used it on my last project and it was cake.

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/08/sqlite-persistent-objects.html

http://www.galloway.me.uk/2009/02/sqlite-persistent-objects/

Answer (score 1):

You might consult these other similar questions:

- ["iPhone create SQLite database at runtime?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019723/iphone-create-sqlite-database-at-runtime)
- ["Where’s the best sqlite3 tutorial for iPhone-SDK?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716839/wheres-the-best-sqlite3-tutorial-for-iphone-sdk)
- ["Add SQLite Database to iphone app"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487339/add-sqlite-database-to-iphone-app)

Additionally, the SQLiteBooks sample code that Apple provides takes you step-by-step through the process of copying an existing database from the resources directory of your application bundle to the application's Documents directory.  It is a little more complex when working with the database, however.

Mobile Orchard also has a [list of resources](http://www.mobileorchard.com/iphone-sqlite-tutorials-and-libraries/) for SQLite on the iPhone.

The source code to my iPhone application [Molecules](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/molecules) is available, and for now it uses SQLite as a data store (that will be changing to Core Data soon).  You may be able to pick something up from that.