# Sqlite create table only in first launch of application

Tags: ios, ios4

I make application with sqlite3. I want to create tables of the app only first time user start application. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to create table in Sqlite3 and save extension sqlite. And to save database in one drive, after use database in Apps that import in your apps.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to do this in the AppDelegate under

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

You would probably check if the database exists first:

```
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *databasePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Database.db"];

BOOL dbExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

if (dbExists == NO) {
   //database doesn't exist
   //create your database here
    sqlite3* db;
    int error;
    if((error = sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &db)) != SQLITE_OK) {
       NSLog(@"sqlite3_open failed(%d) with %@", error, [databasePath UTF8String]);
       sqlite3_close(db);
    }
}
```

See the following question as to why this works: [iPhone create SQLite database at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019723/iphone-create-sqlite-database-at-runtime)

Here is another tutorial:
http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development-tutorials/iphone-sdk-tutorial-reading-data-from-a-sqlite-database/

Answer (score 2):

i think this application code will help you.

```
package x.y;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FirstDemoActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button buttonX = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        buttonX.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("fd",
                        SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);

                db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE tbl1(col1 TEXT, col2 INTEGER)");

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                values.put("col1", "Shaktimaan");
                values.put("col2", 420);

                db.insert("tbl1", null, values);

                db.close();
            }
        });
    }
}
```